# Fabric.js on Node 4+

Tags: node.js, fabricjs

It seems to be a known issue that [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) will fails to install out of the box on node.js >=4.

Is it possible to make it work on node >=4? And if not, is there a way to still use it on a node >=4 app, or does the fact that fabric itself only works on node <4 forces me to write my whole app in <4 as well?

Is it possible to two separate versions of node simultaneously, using v0.12 just to run the `fabric` module, and v4+ for the app itself? Is this approach even worth investigating?